# How much weight would the scale show if we get on a scale with springs on top of it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, spring, weight

Lets say we have a scale and on top of the scale there is a big spring and we get on top of the spring. Suppose we weight 70kg and spring itself weights 2kg and after we get on the spring we compress the spring halfway down so basically the spring isnt bottomed out. How much weight would the scale show? Will it still show 72kg or will it weight less because spring is now absorbing our weight?

Comment: A spring does not absorb weight. Weight is a force, and a spring roughly speaking (and in this context) does not absorb force. It absorbs energy. Your weight and the weight of the spring still must both be carried by the ground or by the scale, so the scale will show 72 kg. If the spring is in motion (oscillating), then the reading will be off, because larger forces are introduced to cause the up-and-down accelerations, forces that the scale will misinterpret as a part of the total weight. But in a stationary scenario, the scale will show the combined, correct 72 kg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The force needed to compress the spring will indirectly act on the scale through the spring, thereby increasing the weight shown. By how much depends on the spring constant $k$ and the compression length $x$ via Hooke's law.</strike>

EDIT: I have misread the question; I thought you somehow externally compressed the spring. If your weight compresses the spring, that will apply a reaction force from the spring to you, but the net force applied to the scale will still be the force of the two weights (body mass + spring). So the weight shown by the scale should just be 70 + 2 kg.